# Vb 6.0 to vb.net conversion

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am converting a project from vb6.0 to vb.net...in vb6.0 i have a function which accepts a one dimension array and the array is used as three dimension in function definition which is not supported in vb.net

For eg:

```
public sub func(ByRef a() as Short)
short i=0
**a(0,1,1) =i**
End sub
```

I am getting the following error
Number of indices exceeds the number of dimensions of the indexed array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method declaration to this:

```
Public Sub Func( a(,,) As Short )
```

Note that you generally don't need to use the `ByRef` keyword in VB.NET for parameters as it's implicit for all Reference Types (such as arrays).

Also, the typical style convention in VB.NET is to use `TitleCase` for all language keywords and methods and `camelCase` for fields, locals and parameters.

(Out of curiosity, if you're converting it by hand, why did you choose to opt for VB.NET rather than C#?)

Comment: Hi thanks you your reply it worked ,i am converting it by hand, i have used a converting tool even then some of the things like activex controls and array indices like above eg. are not converted..regarding c# i am from java background and have no idea about it